# .NET CORE build results in Duplicate Errors in vscode

Tags: build, visual-studio-code, .net-core, intellisense

I am just trying to understand the whole build/publish topic for .NET Core and was playing around with one basic console application.

When I build the app

```
dotnet build
```

and afterwards build it with release configuration

```
dotnet build --configuration Release
```

I receive errors saying

> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
>   [test]

obviously the files

./obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/test.Assembly.info

and

./obj/Release/netcoreapp2.1/test.Assembly.info

store values for the same attributes:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Some further questions to get a clearer picture of this:

- As a DEV, would I delete all Debug stuff before building for release?
- What is the behind-the-scences difference between building for debug or release?
- Why should I ever publish for (default) debug configuration (dotnet publish)?

I've read all the documentation from ms but imo its from and for people more familiar with building processes.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 18):

In short, setting GenerateAssemblyInfo to false in the relevant .csproj should do the trick:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[See this git-issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7153)

[And this one](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7207)

Short explanation:
.NET CORE first introduced the project.json based project system, which replaced AssemblyInfo.cs. Later, project.json was dropped in favor of a more extensive .csproj usage. [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj)

Comment: I originally proposed this as an edit for TGY's answer, as it just extends it with more information and provides the solution directly (links die).